# Argparse not recognized and incorrectly handled

Tags: python, argparse

I have some problems using argparse. I want to have a set of names I can define on the command line which will influence the program's behaviour. I tried the following snippet:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("allon", action='store_true', default = False,
                    help="Toggles all output pins to ON.")
parser.add_argument("alloff",action='store_true',
                    help="Toggles all output pins to OFF.")
parser.add_argument("cont", action='store_true',
                    help="Toggles all output pins continously on and off.")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.allon:
   do_allon()
elif args.alloff:
    do_alloff()
....
```

but the code's behavious is anything than expected. I do not want to use the '--' for those options, as I want to call my code like `git status` (without the leading '--').

First, if I call the code without arguments all the arguments are set to True, while I want them to be set to False if they are not given. The expected behaviour is as follows: When calling as

```
python code.py
```

I want `allon, alloff` and `cont` to be set to `False`, while when calling as

```
python code.py alloff
```

I want `allon` and `cont` to be `False` while `alloff` set to be `True`.

Second, when I call e.g. `python code.py allon` I get

```
code.py: error: unrecognized arguments: allon
```

which I don't understand at all. I know how to use optparse, but help with argparse is greatly appreciated to get the above snippet working.

Thanks
  Alex

P.S. The if-loop is just educational, not actually implemented that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you see a command pattern like `git status`, `git commit`, etc. we are talking about [sub-commands](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#sub-commands). To create sub-commands, argparse lets you use *sub-parsers*, which are essentially just like the main parser (take command-line switches, etc.).

Define them like this:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')

allon_parser = subparsers.add_parser('allon',
    help='Toggles all output pins to ON.')
allon_parser.set_defaults(func=do_allon)

alloff_parser = subparsers.add_parser('alloff',
    help="Toggles all output pins to OFF.")
alloff_parser.set_defaults(func=do_alloff)

cont_parser = subparsers.add_parser('cont',
    help="Toggles all output pins continously on and off.")
cont_parser.set_defaults(func=do_cont)

args = parser.parse_args()
# Call the associated `func` function
args.func()
```

I've associated a function with each subparser (`set_defaults(func=...)`), and thus the `args` structure will have a `func` attribute pointing to one of the functions defined. We simply have to call it.

Output of `--help`:

```
usage: PROG [-h] {cont,alloff,allon} ...

positional arguments:
  {cont,alloff,allon}  sub-command help
    allon              Toggles all output pins to ON.
    alloff             Toggles all output pins to OFF.
    cont               Toggles all output pins continously on and off.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Options are normally specified using a leading `-` for short arguments (1 character) or a leading `--` for long arguments.

Therefore, you should give your optional arguments two leading dashes:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# Note that `default=False` is unnecessary since it's implied by `store_true`.
parser.add_argument("--allon", action='store_true',
                    help="Toggles all output pins to ON.")
parser.add_argument("--alloff",action='store_true',
                    help="Toggles all output pins to OFF.")
parser.add_argument("--cont", action='store_true',
                    help="Toggles all output pins continously on and off.")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.allon:
    do_allon()
elif args.alloff:
    do_alloff()
....
```

Comment: I know, but I wanted to implement this how other commands are handled, for example git commands. You call `git status` and not `git --status`.

Comment: Git "commands" are actually subcommands -- `git X` basically delegates to a command called `git-X`. Each subcommand takes options as usual, e.g. `git add -p`. I would not consider an option called "allon" to be a subcommand, for example.

Comment: @Alex: That's not comparable. The subcommand `status` isn't an optional flag like your arguments are- it's a positional argument. It is always necessary, and there is always exactly one of them. (You could implement it with `parser.add_argument('subcommand')`, and it would exit with the usage message if it were ignored, just like git does).  On the other hand, you *do* use `git status --ignore-submodules`...

Comment: @Alex: Actually, as I mention in my edit, if you want to use subcommands like `git` does you should use the [add_subparser](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) functionality, which lets you break up the command line parsing based on the first argument.

Comment: @Alex: In this case I think you just want a `choices`-limited mandatory first argument; see my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the first argument to your function mandatory, and limit the choices available, do it this way:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("action", action="store", choices=['allon', 'alloff', 'cont'])

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.action == 'allon':
    print 'allon'
elif args.action == 'alloff':
    print 'alloff'
```

Example usage:

```
$ python req_argparse.py allon
allon
$ python req_argparse.py alloff
alloff
$ python req_argparse.py nope
usage: req_argparse.py [-h] {allon,alloff,cont}
req_argparse.py: error: argument action: invalid choice: 'nope' (choose from 'allon', 'alloff', 'cont')
```

Answer (score 0):

When options in `argparse` are optional flags, they should start with `--` like so:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--allon", action='store_true', default = False,
                    help="Toggles all output pins to ON.")
parser.add_argument("--alloff",action='store_true',
                    help="Toggles all output pins to OFF.")
parser.add_argument("--cont", action='store_true',
                    help="Toggles all output pins continously on and off.")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

if we then add the code:

```
print args.allon, args.alloff, args.cont
```

we can demonstrate that your program will have the desired behavior:

```
$ python test.py
False False False
$ python test.py --allon
True False False
$ python test.py --alloff
False True False
$ python test.py --cont
False False True
$ python test.py --allon --alloff --cont
True True True
```

ETA: If you want to have a subcommand equivalent to git's `status`, `add`, `commit`, etc, then optional flags would not be the right way to implement it. You should instead use [argparse's `add_subparsers` functionality](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands).

Comment: @Alex: Did you see my and nneonneo's comments?